# Determining the convergence/divergence of a nearly alternating series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I have to determine the convergence of the following series:

$$1+ \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{5} - \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{7} + \frac{1}{8} - \frac{1}{9} + \ldots$$

Clearly, $\sum |a_n| = \sum \frac{1}{n} $ diverges where $a_n$ is the sequence associated with above infinite series. However, I know that $\sum (-1)^n \frac{1}{n}$ converges by the alternating series test. Is there any way I could the convergence of $\sum (-1)^n \frac{1}{n}$ to prove the convergence/divergence of the infinite series?

Hints would be appreciated. I cannot seem to figure it out.

Comment: $1+(1/4)+(1/7)+\cdots$ diverges. The series omitting these terms converges,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the partial sum of the first $n$ terms be $S_n$.

Generalities when faced with such a sum -

1. **Criteria for convergence** If $S_{3n},S_{3n+1}$, and $S_{3n+2}$ converge to the same limit $l$, then $S_n\to l$. ($3$ because the pattern in signs is in threes)
2. **Criteria for divergence** If a subsequence of $S_n$ does not converge, then $S_n$ cannot converge.

PS note that the sum of only the positive terms and only the negative terms are $\pm\infty$ respectively, so the Riemann rearrangement theorem tells us that rearranging the order of the summands can change the value. Hence, we should refrain from performing a rearrangement.

Specific to this problem - we have [(W|A)](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F(3%20k%20-%202)%20%2B%201%2F(3%20k%20-%201)%20-%201%2F(3%20k))
$$ S_{3n} = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac1{3k-2} + \frac1{3k-1} - \frac1{3k} = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{9 k^{2}-2}{3 k(3 k-2)(3 k-1)}$$
note that for every $k\ge 1$,
$$ \frac{9 k^{2}-2}{3 k(3 k-2)(3 k-1)}\ge \frac{9k^2-2k^2}{(3k)^3} = \frac7{27k}$$
Hence $S_{3n}\to \infty$, and therefore $S_n$ diverges.